# wraping react-navigation/native-stack with <provider> and return as Component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am super confused on how to use `@react-navigation/native-stack`

I have an old project that I need to update.

Previously we used to use `react-navigation`

I used to do this

```
const OverviewStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ...Routes,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Overview",
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      ...SharedHeader(navigation),
    }),
  }
);
```

then wraps by Subscribe and return it as a Component, however now it threw a bunch of error when I try to do this,

```
 ERROR  [Error: TransformError SyntaxError:.... Unexpected token
```

how can I wrap my stack with provider and return it as a component?

```
export default class overviewStackWithStore extends Component {
  static router = OverviewStack.router;
  static propTypes = {
    navigation: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Subscribe
        to={[]}
      >
        {() => (
          <OverviewStack
            navigation={this.props.navigation}
            screenProps={{}}
          />
        )}
      </Subscribe>
    );
  }
}
```